# Oplog tailing & Meteor scaling

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I just go thou the oplog tailing article by meteor

[To use oplog tailing in your production Meteor app, your MongoDB servers must be configured as a replica set; a single-mongod database has no oplog. Your cluster may not use Mongo sharding](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver#oplogobservedriver-in-production)

is that mean now one can only vertically scale the MongoDB but not horizontally, which is kind of contradictory to what MongoDB specialize in ?

Answer (score 0):

> [does that mean ...] one can only vertically scale the MongoDB but not horizontally [...] ?

No, it doesn't. Horizontal scaling is achieved through sharding, and [each shard can be a replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#how-does-sharding-work-with-replication), which offers replication and hence, oplogs that can be tailed.